# What does /recursive actually do in Team Foundation Server Power Tools?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I regularly use Team Foundation Server Power Tools to run a scorch, treeclean, uu, etc.. Most of these tools have an option for /recursive that is described as

> /recursive  Switch from one level of recursion to full recursion

I've scoured the internet and am still unsure what /recursive actually does. An example question that I've been unable to tell the difference between running "tfpt scorch" vs "tfpt scorch /recursive".

It seems like something that probably increases the time the tool takes to run while making it (somehow) better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/recursive` switch is typically available on commands which affect version control folders or files. It is used to indicate that you want to perform the task on a specified folder and all of it's sub folders.

i.e. If you have a version control folder structure similar to `$/MyTeamProject/MyBranch/MyFolder/SomeSubFolders` and you have checked out all of the files. You know that you haven't changed all of the files so you could run `tfpt uu $/MyTeamProject/MyBranch/MyFolder`. This will undo the pending changes on the files that haven't changed but only for `MyFolder`, if you add `/recursive` it will undo changes in `MyFolder` and all of the targets sub folders as well

Comment: When using /recursive without a path, "tfpt scorch /recursive", it seems to be the same as "tfpt scorch". It will behave recursively, scorching the whole workspace (and subfolders). If you specify a path, then the recursive switch matters. With a path specified and no recursive switch, only that directory will be scorched. I'll re-accept your answer.